# Issue with ListView content (viewHolder is not altering views inside)

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been looking for the answer to my problem, and I've found similar entries and have fixed some things but not the main problem.
When I run my code all thumbnails' images are the same and there is no text displaying in the TextViews, even though the Log.D is showing I'm changing the textViews to the correct texts and images. 
My activity code:

```
ListView lvMaterias;
String[] materiasNombre;
int[] thumbnails={R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui,
        R.drawable.thumbnailanato,
        R.drawable.thumbnailbioqui};
List<materiaRow> materiasObjetos= new ArrayList<materiaRow>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select);
    //inicializar los arrays y todo
    lvMaterias = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMaterias);
    materiasNombre=this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombreMateria);
    int i=0;
    for (String nombre : materiasNombre){
        Log.d("loop", nombre);
        materiasObjetos.add(new materiaRow(thumbnails[i],nombre, "0%"));
    }
lvMaterias.setAdapter(new materiasAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rowmateria, materiasObjetos));
}

}
```

My Adapter Class, the log.d at the getView method show I have the correct text and images, but textViews are not getting changes:

```
public class materiasAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements     View.OnClickListener{
private int layout;
public materiasAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    layout=resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    materiaHolder mH;
    if (convertView==null){
        mH= new materiaHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView= inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        mH.thumbnail= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivthumbnail);
        mH.materia= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvmateria);
        mH.porcentaje= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvporcentaje);
        mH.favorito = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bfavoritos);
        mH.favorito.setOnClickListener(this);
        convertView.setTag(mH);
    }
    else {
        mH= (materiaHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    materiaRow mR= (materiaRow) getItem(position);
    mH.thumbnail.setImageResource(mR.getThumbnail());
    mH.porcentaje.setText(mR.getPorcentaje());
    Log.d("thumbnail", Integer.toString(mR.getThumbnail()));
    mH.materia.setText(mR.getMateria());
    Log.d("texto", mR.getMateria());
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}

class materiaHolder {
    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView materia;
    TextView porcentaje;
    Button favorito;
}
}
```

XML as requested (Select Activity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.quetzal.elite.Select">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvMaterias" />
```

And rowMateria (resource of the adapter class):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/ivthumbnail" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvmateria" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvporcentaje" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="fav"
    android:id="@+id/bfavoritos" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: When I ran this, I found that the text actually was showing up, but it was the same color as the background. in your rowMateria.xml, can you try settign the linearlayouts background to black with `android:background="@android:color/black"`

Comment: How would you even notice that .-. ... anyway, marked as solved, perhaps it has anything to do with my theme? how can I change it so text is black as default?

Comment: If you look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html  and work from there - I am defnitely not the expert.  I noticed it by inspecting the element with UIAutomatorView in $ANDROID_SDK/tools/uiautomatorviewer.bat  You can take a "screenshot" and highlight items, and it shows you whats in the actual view.

Comment: Props to you Mr Matthew, I'd been stuck into this like for ages without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the issue with the thumgnail goes... In your main onCreate(), it doesn't look like you aren't adding the rows correctly.

```
int i=0;
for (String nombre : materiasNombre){
    Log.d("loop", nombre);
    materiasObjetos.add(new materiaRow(thumbnails[i],nombre, "0%"));
}
```

You need to increment i, or you will always get thumbnails[0].

Comment: you are right, thumbnails were not correct, strange thing, thumbnails do change, but text is still blank.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, for whatever reason on my emulator, the text color and background color were the same - So the text was being set, but you could not see it.

You can set up your background on the activity as something specific like

`android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark"`

and the text with something like

`android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"`

I'm not very well versed on the preferred methods of setting the background and text colors - longer term you should be looking at the themes I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the ViewHolder class static like here:
https://github.com/isaacurbina/ViewHolderListView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mac/isaac/viewholderlistview/MyArrayAdapter.java

Hope it helps!